# how to insert new line in vimscript substitiute function

Tags: function, newline, vim, substitution

I want this sentence:

```
My, sentence.
```

To be like this:

```
My,
sentence.
```

My function is:

```
function! ParseLine()
   let line = getline(".")
   echom line 
   let parsedLine  = substitute(line, ",", "\v\\v\\0\\r\r\\n\r\\<cr>\<cr><cr>\\^M\r&\^@\\^@", "g")
   call setline(".", parsedLine)
endfunction
```

What I get when running this function:

```
Myvv,^M^M^@^M<cr>^M<cr>^M^M,^@^@ sentence.
```

Comment: Note, you can use single quotes rather than double quotes in most cases to drastically reduce the number of backslashes needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way:

```
function! ParseLine()
   exec 's/,\s*/,\r/g'
endfunction
```

Or if you want to first call `substitute()` then "set" that line:

```
function! ParseLine()
   let parsedLine  = substitute(getline('.'), ',\s*', ',\n', "g")
   let o = @o
   let @o = parsedLine
   normal! V"op
   let @o=o
endfunction
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you are trying to do it is never going to work because you can't use newlines in the `setline` function.

If you try to use `setline` on a string that contains a newline you will get an error. However, you could do this with an `execute "normal! ..."` command:

```
function! ParseLine()
    execute "normal! 0f,a\n"
endfunction
```

That should find the `,` and insert a newline after it, giving you the result you want.

Note that you have to use `execute "normal! ..."` as opposed to `normal! ...` because normal won't understand that `\n` is a special character and you would get:

```
My,\n Sentence
```

Comment: in OP's codes, he had a `'g'` flag in `substitute()`, your answer will just replace the first comma.

Comment: No, it won't replace the first comma, it will insert a newline after the first comma.

Comment: What I meant was, you just handle the **first** comma, no matter replace or whatever... but OP wanted the handling on **all** commas. he had `g` in his codes.

Comment: Thank You, but I'm doing more stuff with that line, not only putting enters after commas. Kent answer is more usuefull for my problem.